# Editable ComboBox with selectedvalue(path) from itemsource OR user input

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

Hey I'm trying to create a combobox that allows a user to select an item from the list (shown in list as fx. "2324 - James - 21"), put a property from that item in the textbox (fx. "James"), but also allow for user input of that one property. (fx. "Jack")

What I've got so far is a combobox that allows for user input, but when an item is selected, instead of the property (As specified in SelectedValuePath), the items **ToString** is put in the combobox text field, instead of just the name.
Any ideas how to fix it? This is my setup now:

Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id} - {Name} - {Age}";
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding PersonName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding People, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
SelectedValue="{Binding PersonName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
IsEditable="True" SelectedValuePath="Name" />
```

**Edit:**

People is an ObservableCollection<Person>, PersonName is a string bound to a field personName and OnPropertyChanged(); is called in its set method. The ViewModel Inherits from an ObservableObject class that implements INotifyPropertychanged.

**Edit 2:**

Okay, so I've been trying this instead:

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding PersonName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding People, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
SelectedItem="{Binding Person, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
IsEditable="True" />
```

Aaand in the viewmodel:

```
public Person SelectedPerson
{
    get => selectedPerson;
    set
    {
        selectedPerson = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (SelectedPerson != null) PersonName = SelectedPerson.Name;
    }
}
```

Buuut, when I select a person from the list, the combbox text field is set to Persons ToString value, not SelectedPerson.Name... Or rather; it's probably set to SelectedPerson.Name first, but then SelectedPerson.ToString() automatically by the ComboBox :/

**Edit 3:**

Alright, I've been trying to interrupt the text change, when it comes from SelectionChanged in a really hacky way, but I can't figure out how to "Cancel" a text change. Here's my code so far, but TextChanged doesn't seem to allow for reverting the text, as far as I can see, and PreviewTextInput is only triggered when the change is form user input :/.

```
Useless code removed. Almost identical to edit 4, but without the "oldtext" field.
```

**Edit 4:**

I solved it, in a horrible way. It works, but I really wish there was a better way. Maybe one of you has a better solution? :) Anyway this is the solution I came to:

Dependency property thing that reverts text after it's been forcefully changed by the combobox:

```
public class ComboBoxBehaviour
{
    private static bool overrideTextChange;
    private static string oldText;

    public static bool GetDisconnectTextFromSelectedItem(ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        return (bool)comboBox.GetValue(DisconnectTextFromSelectedItemProperty);
    }
    public static void SetDisconnectTextFromSelectedItem(ComboBox comboBox, bool value)
    {
        comboBox.SetValue(DisconnectTextFromSelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisconnectTextFromSelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DisconnectTextFromSelectedItem",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(ComboBoxBehaviour),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnDisconnectTextFromSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnDisconnectTextFromSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = d as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox == null) return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false) return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            comboBox.SelectionChanged += HandleSelection;
            comboBox.Loaded += ComboBoxOnLoaded;
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox.SelectionChanged -= HandleSelection;
            comboBox.Loaded -= ComboBoxOnLoaded;
        }
    }
    private static void ComboBoxOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)e.Source;
        TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)comboBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBox);
        txtBox.TextChanged += TxtBoxOnTextChanged;
    }
    private static void TxtBoxOnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (overrideTextChange)
        {
            ((TextBox) e.Source).Text = oldText;
            overrideTextChange = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private static void HandleSelection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)e.Source;
        TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)comboBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBox);
        oldText = txtBox.Text;
        overrideTextChange = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Xaml combobox:

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding PersonName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding People, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
SelectedItem="{Binding Person, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
IsEditable="True" helpers:ComboBoxBehaviour.DisconnectTextFromSelectedItem="True" />
```

**Edit 5:**
Close, but no cigar. turns out calling

```
((TextBox) e.Source).Text = oldText;
```

does not update my combobox text binding, so it shows the correct text, but the string in the viewmodel is wrong - it's the ToString text, instead of the short text. So how do I force the combobox binding to refresh, when I don't have access to the combobox in the text change context? More "hacking"? Hmm...

**Edit 6:**
Alright I got it working by changing TxtBoxOnTextChanged to this;

```
private static void TxtBoxOnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (overrideTextChange) //The combo box changed the text of the textbox.
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox) e.Source; //The textbox
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)textBox.TemplatedParent; //The combobox.
        comboBox.Text = oldText; //Set the text of the combobox to update the property on the viewmodel.
        textBox.Text = oldText; //Set the text of the textbox manually, because setting the combobox text doesn't change it for some reason.
        overrideTextChange = false;
        e.Handled = true; //Done!
    }
}
```

Still hoping someone's got a better solution, but it works!

Comment: What happens if you remove `Text="{Binding PersonName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" `?

Comment: @mm8 If I remove the text binding it still shows the ToString value in the combobox, but PersonName is correctly set to the Name property, but if the user enters a name manually, PersonName is not set.

Comment: Set the DisplayMemberPath to Name?

Comment: @mm8 Can't do that, then the items in the list only shows Name - I need the list to have the full ToString value. Also doesn't affect user input

Comment: In the actual list that pops up i need to show ToString, but in the manual input field I need to show only the Name property.

Comment: Then you should set `PersonName` to the string that you want to display in the input field and don't bind `SelectedValue` to `PersonName`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the value of the `Name` property instead of `ToString()`, you should set the `DisplayMemberPath` property to "Name".

> I need to show ToString in the list, but Name in the input field.

Then you should set `PersonName` to the `string` that you want to display in the input field and don't bind `SelectedValue` to `PersonName`.

You can only actually select a value that's in the source collection.

Comment: I need to show ToString in the list, but Name in the input field.

Comment: The input field shows the currently selected value and you can only select a value that's in the `ItemsSource` collection.

Comment: Alright that makes a lot of sense. I tried something similar first without success. Tried it again just in case and updated my question. Still not quite right :/